# python [SSL] PEM lib (_ssl.c:3309) error when verifying certificate

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, ssl-certificate

I am trying to send POST messages to a web server.
In order to do that, I am using python requests and trying to pass the requests.post method a certificate as an argument.

It looks something like that:

```
    if method_type == METHOD_TYPE_GET:
        resp = requests.get(base_url, data=request_data, verify=True, headers=headers, cert=certificate)
    if method_type == METHOD_TYPE_POST:
        resp = requests.post(base_url, data=request_data, verify=True, headers=headers, cert=certificate)
    return resp
```

When 'certificate' is the path to a pem file, which contains the server's certificate. The file is of format:

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----

-base64data-

-----END CERTIFICATE-----

When I try to execute the post method, I get an Exception of: [SSL] PEM lib (_ssl.c:3309)

Any idea what the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please check your openssl - configuration file setting for the following parameter
extendedKeyUsage = clientAuth